# How to get return value from function which is triggered on 'click'? Jquery Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to get this return value?
I have tried with outside function placed in variable, with the name of this variable in onclick listener, but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).on('click','#box', function(){ 
        var box = 20;
        return box;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  you can't return from that function. However you can declare a global variable and use it later.

```
var box =0;
$(document).on('click','#box', function(){ 
        box = 20;  
 });
// use box later.
```